# Loop login 16.04 after security update

Tags: 16.04, updates, login, lightdm

I have been using ubuntu 16.04 for 5 to 6 months with minor problems that I was able to fix. Recently, I checked the software updater and told me that there was a software update. After installing it everything worked fine. However when I rebooted I tried logging in but I would be redirected back to the login screen. I have an AMD graphics card and until now I have tried and failed to make everything work normal again by doing:

-Reinstalling and reconfiguring lightdm

-Installing gdm (and then back to lightdm)

-moving .Xauthority to Xauthority.bak

-chown user:user .Xauthority

-sudo apt-get clean && autoremove

I am heavily dependent on my computer so can someone help?

Comment: Please provide the kernel version you are using with `uname -r`.

Comment: I had something similar with an nvidia card and a recent kernel update. Restart the machine and keep hitting Esc to get to the Grub loading screen. Select advanced options and try booting into a previous kernel.

Comment: I tried using previous kernels but with no luck